# Dictionary using is custom key but key is always unequal

Tags: c#, dictionary, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer, containskey

I am using RTBTextPointer as custom key in dictionary...

```
   Init.SpintaxEditorPropertyMain.SpintaxListDict = new Dictionary<RTBTextPointer, SpintaxEditorProperties.SpintaxMappedValue>(new RTBTextPointerComparer());
```

I worte this RTBTextPointer, and RTBTextPointerComparer classes in class library and using this in different wpf projects,

```
 if (Init.SpintaxEditorPropertyMain.SpintaxListDict.ContainsKey(_index) == false)
        {
            Init.SpintaxEditorPropertyMain.SpintaxListDict.Add(_index,_SpintaxMappedVal);
        }
```

everytime containsKey returns false, even it contains, so duplication entry occurs in dictionary.. is anything wrong in my "GetHashCode()"

```
    public class RTBTextPointer
    {
    static int _row;
    static int _column;

    public int Row
    {
        get
        {
            return _row;
        }
        set
        {
            _row = value;
        }
    }
    public int Column
    {
        get
        {
            return _column;
        }
        set
        {
            _column = value;
        }
    }

}

public class RTBTextPointerComparer : IEqualityComparer<RTBTextPointer>
{
    public bool Equals(RTBTextPointer x, RTBTextPointer y)
    {         
        bool result = int.Equals(x.Column, y.Column) && (int.Equals(x.Row, y.Row));

        return result;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(RTBTextPointer obj)
    {
        var result = 0;
        int hCode = obj.Column ^ obj.Row;
        result = hCode.GetHashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Always Key is not equal, even those are equal.. ?

Comment: everyt time containskey returns false                               if(Init.SpintaxEditorPropertyMain.SpintaxListDict.ContainsKey (_index) == false)
            {
                Init.SpintaxEditorPropertyMain.SpintaxListDict.Add(_index,_SpintaxMappedVal);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a separate comparer. Just overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` should suffice.

Also, if you have very simple properties like that, you could switch to [auto properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384054.aspx)

```
public class RTBTextPointer
{
    public int Row
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Column
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        var other = obj as RTBTextPointer;
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return other.Row == Row && other.Column == Column;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // 397 or some other prime number
            return (Row * 397) ^ Column;
        }
    }
}
```

See [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/a569z7k8.aspx) for more information about that.

If you have more than two properties, and if those properties could be null, the `GetHashCode` might look like this:

```
unchecked
{
    var result = 0;
    result = (result * 397) ^ (Prop1 != null ? Prop1.GetHashCode() : 0);
    result = (result * 397) ^ (Prop2 != null ? Prop2.GetHashCode() : 0);
    result = (result * 397) ^ (Prop3 != null ? Prop3.GetHashCode() : 0);
    result = (result * 397) ^ (Prop4 != null ? Prop4.GetHashCode() : 0);
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably stems from the following declarations in `RTBTextPointer`:

```
static int _row;
static int _column;
```

These don't do what I think you're intending. They should be

```
private int _row; 
private int _column;
```

As it is right now, these variables reference `static` members of `RTBTextPointer`. This means that any access of them will access or mutate the `static` members of it. `static` members are accessible to every instance of a type. If you make them `private`, they will apply per instance, which I believe is your intent.

Once that is corrected, I would reconsider the design of your class, at least if you intent to use it as a key in a `Dictionary`. `RTBTextPointer` should be immutable, or atleast the fields and properties that `GetHashCode()` depends on. Here's why:

When you add a object as a key to a dictionary, it's associated value is placed in a hash bucket , which is simply some data structure associated with a hash code. Assume we have some arbitrary key `RTBTextPointer` with `Row = 2` and `Column = 2` and a value of "Foo". It's GetHashCode would be 0 (2 XOR 2).

```
Hash Key                  Value
0    RTBTextPointer(2,2)  Foo
```

Right now, a call to `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` would return true looking for `RTBTextPointer(2,2)`. Now consider if this `RTBTextPointer` changed to have a `Row = 4`. It's hash code would now be 6 (4 XOR 2). The call to `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` would now be false, and the value `Foo` would be inaccessible because the key has a hash code that depends upon mutable state.

As a final note, I would consider overriding the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods of `object`.

Comment: Totally missed the `static`. Nice catch!